# In ns-3 simulator when to use p2p nodes, wifistanodes and csmanodes

Tags: initialization, nodes, ns-3

I'm trying to use NS-3 simulator to do some tests between random waypoint model and some other models. While during the simulation I found that when need to run the simulation we need to initiate the model by using a class called

> MobilityHelper

Code below is the part of the code that I am using. During the initialization, there are some nodes need to be created beforehand such as

> p2pNodes
>
> csmaNodes

So what do these nodes mean, and in which situation need to use them? Are they specify to some specific mobility models? If so please give some details, many thanks!

```
  NodeContainer p2pNodes;
  p2pNodes.Create (3);

  PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
  pointToPoint.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("5Mbps"));
  pointToPoint.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("2ms"));

  NetDeviceContainer p2pDevices;
  p2pDevices = pointToPoint.Install (p2pNodes);

  NodeContainer csmaNodes;
  csmaNodes.Add (p2pNodes.Get (1));
  csmaNodes.Create (nCsma);

  CsmaHelper csma;
  csma.SetChannelAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("100Mbps"));
  csma.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", TimeValue (NanoSeconds (6560)));

  NetDeviceContainer csmaDevices;
  csmaDevices = csma.Install (csmaNodes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p2pNodes` and `csmaNodes` are simply variable names for the `NodeContainer` used in this particular example in order to keep track of nodes for the two networks (the Point-to-Point and the CSMA). The fact that you named them `p2pNodes` and `csmaNodes` is only for your own convenience. What matters are the types of `NetDevice`s that end up being installed on these nodes.

In any case, that has nothing to do with the `MobilityModel` that you install.
Both P2P and CSMA are wired networks and I wouldn't think of adding a random mobility on those. It wouldn't make sense to move around with a wire attached to you..!

Note that the above example code will crash, as you have created 3 `p2pNodes`, and a point-to-point link can only be instantiated between two nodes.

I would recommend studying the ns-3 tutorial to get an understanding of the concepts of `Node`, `NodeContainer` (ie. vectors of Nodes), `NetDevice` (ie. the network card/type), `MobilityModel` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as for the reason to use these two networks just simply because I am new to NS3 and trying to alter the example codes to fit in my case. But you are right, there is something weird happens: even I changed the mobility model name and the value of the nodes, the results remain the same(but not crash)! (it aways as same as the sample code results) I feel confused about this, can I ask why?

Comment: I would love to hear some advices from you that if I want to test ramdom way point model in ns-3 what kind of network do I need to use? (I guess should not be wired network right?)

Comment: Using p2p or csma would not have any change in the results even if you change the mobility because these are wired networks. To see any type of difference, you need to use a wireless network, e.g. wifi. There are several examples in /examples/wireless folder (some may be using random mobility)